# When can Jordan's lemma be applied to contours less than a complete semicircle?

Tags: complex-analysis

[This paper](http://www.itcanbeshown.com/integrals/Fresnel%20Integrals/fresnel_integrals.pdf) on the evaluation of the Fresnel integral $\int_0^\infty \cos (x^2)\, dx$ claims that the Jordan lemma (see the bottom of page 3) shows that if $C_R$ is the eighth-circle contour $\{R e^{i t}:0 \leq t \leq \pi/4\}$, then $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_R} e^{iz^2}\, dz = 0.$$

The explanation glosses over why Jordan's lemma, which applies to semicircular contours in the upper half-plane, can be used even though $C_R$ is not a complete semicircle.  I'm adapting the paper's approach to evaluating the more general integral $\int_0^\infty \cos (x^a)\, dx$ for $a > 1$ (this is a homework problem, if it matters), and understanding why the Jordan lemma can be used is a stumbling block for me.

Comment: I believe what I am saying is correct, but I am not certain so I will post it as a comment. If your integral is not from $-\infty \rightarrow \infty$ you can split it up into three parts: $C_x$ on the x-axis (R going to infinity), $C_R$ the arc, and $C_L$, the part past the imaginary axis. For example, on $C_L$ you have $z=re^{i2\pi/3}$ with $0\leq r \leq R$, and you compute that integral. In this case, your $C_L$ will actually be going from $R$ to 0 as you are going towards the origin. You can show the integrand vanishes on this integral the usual way.

Comment: if this doesn't make sense I can upload a picture, let me know if that would be helpful.

Comment: Are you talking about a closed contour that includes segments on the axes?  I know that the integral around the closed contour is zero from the residue theorem, but I'm confused specifically about why the integral over the curved segment by itself is zero.  (Is "contour" a word generally reserved for closed curves?  If it is, I can edit my question title.)

Comment: Right, you have segments on the axis. I am not sure about "contour" being reserved for closed curves, but in this case you are dealing with a closed contour; I think you can leave the title as it is. On the curve you have $z=Re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ for example. Because you have an entire function here you can choose to range $\theta$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{\pi}{4}$ or any number which is convenient because you are not enclosing any singularities. You can then plug the z-value, integrate, and find it goes to zero as $R\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: If you take the modulus of the entire integral you can get an inequality that depends only on $R$ and not $\theta$ as $|e^{i \theta}|$ = 1.

Comment: I don't think we quite understand each other.  The path in question **isn't** a closed contour - it's an arc that extends from $R$ to $R e^{i\pi/4}$.

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood. I have the entire solution I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For $z=Re^{i\theta}$ where $0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ we have

$\left| \int_{C_R} e^{iz^2}dz\right| = \left| \int_0^{\pi/4} e^{iR^2(\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta)}iRe^{i\theta}d\theta\right|$ $\leq  \int_0^{\pi/4} e^{-R^2\sin(2\theta)} Rd\theta$

Where I have used that $|e^{iy}|=1$ for any real argument $y$. Then, we use the inequality $\sin(2x)\geq \frac{4x}{\pi}$ for $0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ to find

$\int_0^{\pi/4} e^{-R^2\sin(2\theta)} Rd\theta \leq \int_0^{\pi/4} Re^{-R^2 4\theta/\pi}d\theta$ = $\frac{\pi}{4R}(1-e^{-R^2}) \rightarrow 0$ as $R \rightarrow \infty$.

I think this is what you want, correct? Furthermore note that this can be adapted for any argument of this type, if you have some parameter $p$ such that you have $e^{ipz^2}$ you get the same result.

Comment: I understand why that argument works, but I was especially interested in why this can be argued as an extension of Jordan's lemma, which your argument doesn't use.

Comment: Have you looked at a proof of Jordan's lemma? This is almost the exact same method. You can throw in a function $f(z)\rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow \infty$ and the same result holds, just as in Jordan's lemma.

Comment: I looked up a proof, and it seems you're right; the ones I could find use a similar method.

Comment: This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but I am not sure how else to justify it as being similar to Jordan's Lemma. I hope the justification is sufficient to you and if you find another parallel I would be interested in hearing about it.